# Comparison between $n$ and $\ln (n)$.

Tags: inequality, logarithms, exponential-function, binomial-theorem

Suppose there exists a $n_0>1, \alpha>0$ such that for all $n >n_0$ following is true: $n- \frac{1}{\alpha}\ln (n) > \frac{n}{2}$. How to find the $n_0$?

Comment: Your inequality is equivalent to $n < \exp \left( {\frac{\alpha }{2}n} \right)$. If $\alpha  \ge \frac{2}{e}$, this is true for all $n\geq 1$. If $0 < \alpha  < \frac{2}{e}$, it is true for $n >  - \frac{2}{\alpha }W_{ - 1} \left( { - \frac{\alpha }{2}} \right)$ where $W_{-1}$ is a branch of the Lambert $W$-function.